# How to make a fixed Toast notification

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm new to Windows Phone development and I've found something about background agents in WP 7.5:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP7ScheduledTaskAgent-6450bcf1

I wasn't able to find a way of making the toast notification fixed, I mean, when it appears on the screen it should disappear.

Is there any way of doing this? any advices, documentation should be great.

Thanks.

Comment: A background agent is a small piece of code that runs every 15 minutes on the phone. What you're talking about is a Toast message, which is a visible notification that appears at the top of the screen - what would you like to do with it?

Comment: I want to make the toast notification to not dissappear and when I tap on it , the back function in the phone will be executed. I've found how to create the toast notification but not sure how to make it stay in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Toast Notification by the OS**

When a toast notification is created, the OS handles the amount of time it is displayed for...

> A toast notification displays for about 10 seconds unless the user
>   dismisses it with a flick to the right. If the user taps the toast, by
>   default, your app's start screen launches. Or, you can choose to
>   specify which screen of your app will launch.

*Taken from [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Howitworks).*

The API for toast notifications does **not** allow you to specify a time. Only a title, content and deep link into your app. This is **the only** type of toast/notification that can be used by a Background Agent. But it will appear:

1. on the Start screen
2. when your app is being used
3. when any other app is being used.

### **Custom toast-like notification (eg. [Coding4Fun Toolkit's Toast Prompt](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Toast%20Prompt&referringTitle=Documentation))**

A custom toast notification, although more flexible, must obey all the system rules unlike the system's Toast Notification which has special permissions.

This means the Coding4Fun Toolkit's Toast Prompt cannot:

1. Display notifications when your app is not running (apps cannot run in the background, they are essentially paused)
2. Display notifications when the user is on the Start screen or not using your app

Having a permanently (or long) displaying toast notification would be annoying to the user (hence the 10 second limit by the OS version) so do think carefully about why you need it - is the [`System Tray`](http://blog.duc.as/2011/10/08/using-the-system-tray-to-show-progress-in-windows-phone-7-mango/) or `MessageBox` a better idea?

If you're new to Windows Phone, I would recommend using a handset for a while to get the feel for how the system works and how other apps use all kinds of notifications.

Comment: I'm using the custom toast notification of coding4fun which allows me to specify a time..but the main problem is that I don't know how to make the application run in background.

Comment: The whole idea is that the back button on my phone which is using the wp 7 , is not working , and I need to find a way to add a function on the screen so I can use the "go back" since the button is not working..and it seems that I cant find a way:(

Comment: This question deals with toast notifications, if you have another question that deals with the Back button and how you'd like to use it in your app, then ask a new question about it.

Comment: Ok,using this code http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP7ScheduledTaskAgent-6450bcf1 , do you have any idea where can I change when the toast is tapped ? because when I tap it it opens the application which started the task ,

Comment: Yes, use `toast.NavigationUri` to specify a page within your app - when the user taps on the toast, it will load your app and go to that page.